# How to get Id of edit text on click of dynamically created edit text in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am creating dynamically views in layout according to project requirements. Sequence of views  are coming from json .when i click on edit text then timepicker function called for setting time in edit text ,but when i set the edit text value then its gives the id of last created edit text.
here is my code:-

```
for (i = 0; i < alist_interface_type.size(); i++) {
                 if(alist_interface_type.get(i).equals("textbox")) {
                        LinearLayout lLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                        lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                        lLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        lLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E0E0"));
                        label = new TextView(getActivity());
                        label.setText(example.get(i));
                        label.setTextSize(16);
                        label.setTextColor((Color.parseColor("#01c534")));
                        label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        et = new EditText(getActivity());
                        et.setSingleLine(true);
                        et.setId(i);
                        et.setTextSize(18);
                        et.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        if (!data_type.get(i).toString().equals("text")) {
                            InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
                            filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(Integer.parseInt(data_type.get(i).toString())); 
                            et.setFilters(filters);
                        }
                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        lLayout.addView(label, lp);
                        lLayout.addView(et, lp);
                        ll.addView(lLayout);
                        lp.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 5);
                        lLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        alist_id.add(i);
                        alist_views.add("EditText");
                    }
                else if (alist_interface_type.get(i).equals("time") {
                    LinearLayout lLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                    lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    lLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    lLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E0E0"));
                    label = new TextView(getActivity());
                    label.setText(example.get(i));
                    label.setTextSize(16);
                    label.setTextColor((Color.parseColor("#01c534")));
                    label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    et2 = new EditText(getActivity())
                    {
                        public boolean getDefaultEditable() {
                            return false;
                        }
                    };
                    et2.setSingleLine(true);
                    et2.setId(i);
                    et2.setTextSize(18);
                    Log.d("edit text cliked", ""+i);
                    et2.setText(pref.getString(alist_Label_name.get(i),""));
                    et2.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    if (!data_type.get(i).toString().equals("text")) {
                        InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
                        filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(Integer.parseInt(data_type.get(i).toString())); 
                        et2.setFilters(filters);
                    }
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    lLayout.addView(label, lp);
                    lLayout.addView(et2, lp);
                    lp.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 5);
                    lLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    ll.addView(lLayout);
                    alist_id.add(i);
                    alist_views.add("time");
                    et2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            Log.d("id of edit text", ""+et2.getId());
                            timePicker();
                        }
                    });
                }

                    }
```

In  this code alist_interface_type is arraylist that containing my views.If this list contains "time" then create edit text and click on edit text call time picker method for selecting time and set to edit text.I am giving the value of i to id of edit text.On click of edit text it doesn't give the id of particular clicked edit text to set the value .
[image]

Comment: use setTag() method to identify the field

Comment: i think you have to one listener for your timepicker() time select when time is selected listener return selected time and you set this time to your edittext,

Comment: @BirajZalavadia its not a list view .i am creating dynamically views in layout .

Comment: @Haresh Views are coming from json from server.When i click on edit text then it gives the last edit text 's id not clicked edit text's id.

Comment: so what you can setTag() to any view. What I mean you setTag() your edittext with its label value and in onClick() you can identify by getTag() that which edittext is clicked

Comment: @BirajZalavadia i have done et2.setTag(i); and click of this et2.getTag() it also giving the last edit text's id.

Comment: Do not use e2.getId() but v.getId(); Maybe you have to cast. And continue with timePicker(v);

Comment: @greenapps ya i have used v.getId() and its giving correct id.Thank u so much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

et2.setTag(et2.getId());
et2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      Log.d("id of edit text", ""+et2.getId());
      timePicker(new OnTimeSelected(){
           public void onSelect(String time){
               ((EditText)v.getTag()).setText(time);
           }
      });
    }
});


interface OnTimeSelected{
  public void onSelect(String time);
}
```