# How to create programmatically EditText and then get its value

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to create phone fields programmatically in a form. How to identify it and subsequently get its values?.

The code that create the `EditText` fields and add to a form is this:

```
public void addTelephone(){           
          //form
          TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
          //new row
          TableRow tr = new TableRow(NewRequestActivity.this);

          LayoutParams ltr = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          ltr.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 2500);
          tr.setLayoutParams(ltr);
          //new field
          EditText et = new EditText(NewRequestActivity.this);
          et.setHint("telephone");
          et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);     
          et.requestFocus();
          Resources res = getResources();
          float fontSize = res.getDimension(R.dimen.input_form) / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
          et.setTextSize(fontSize);

          LayoutParams let = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);

          et.setLayoutParams(let);

          ImageView img = new ImageView(NewRequestActivity.this);
          img.setTag("img_"+counttelf);
          img.setImageResource(R.drawable.more);
          img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagefocused);
          img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {               

                      v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      addTelephone();
                }
            });
          LayoutParams limg = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          img.setLayoutParams(limg);

          tr.addView(et, 0);
          tr.addView(img, 1);
table.addView(tr, ++indextelf);
    }
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577420/how-to-get-id-of-edit-text-on-click-of-dynamically-created-edit-text-in-android/23577508#23577508

Answer (score 1):

You can just setTag to your EditText

Eg:

You have phone field:

```
editText.setTag("phone");
```

And when you want to retrieve it.

Just do,

```
EditText ed = (EditText)findViewByTag("phone");
String text = ed.getText().toString();
```

Comment: what is `view` variable?

Comment: I want to get the values of EditText with `"telephone"+counter` tag when click in a "send" button

Comment: you can modify my answer according to the logic and view is nothing but anything like editText or TextView. in your case it is editText

Comment: Then when I click in send button `view` is the `view` of `onclicklistener` of the send button?. `getTag` method waits a `int` parameter or nothing. Is correct?

Comment: EditText ed = (EditText)findViewByTag("phone"); String text = ed.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

set Id to each dynamically created edit text and get values with reference to their id.
To set Id:

```
edittext.setId(i);
```

To get from Id:

```
int i = edittext.getId();
```